# Swift: Insert variable into a label?

Tags: swift, variables, label

I want to insert a variable character into an `UIViewController` label:

e.g. "`Currency = $`" when `$` is a variable and could be **$, £, €** depending.

How do you program with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to make separate variables for each currency characters and then append them to a string. After you can then set the text of that label to be that string.

```
let currencyCharacter:String = "$"
let viewControllerLabelText:String = "Currency = " + currencyCharacter
myViewControllerLabel.text = viewControllerLabelText
```

Answer (score 2):

You would do:

```
var letter = "$"
// You create a new uilabel named label
label.text = "Currency = " + letter
```

You wanna change your letter var depending on your conditional(s).

Here is an example:

```
// var currency is a string used to
// read a paragraph 
 If(currency == "dollar") 
      letter = "$"
 Else if (currency == "British pound")
      letter = "£"
 Else if (currency == "yen")
      letter = "¥"
 ...

 label.text = "Currency = " + letter
```

Here is a reference: [strings and characters: Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation by wrapping a variable in `\()` like this:

```
let currency = "$"
currencyLabel.text = "Currency = \(currency)"
```

This inserts the value of that variable into the surrounding string.
Look here for more information on this topic: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a clean approach into this:

```
func currencySymbol(currency: String) -> String {
    switch currency {
        case "dollar": return "$"
        case "British pound": return "£"
        case "yen": return "¥"
        ///add others as needed
        default: return currency
    }
}

let string =  "Currency = \(currencySymbol("dollar"))"    //"Currency = $"
```